# Out of memory error in EA

Tags: enterprise-architect

When i try to generate the relationship matrix in EA we are getting the "out of memory" dialog is getting show up every time.What might be the reasons for this issue.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are too many reasons to guess and I've never encountered this. Here are a few things you can do:

- Run the Project Integrity Check and see if it solves the issue.
- Look into `%appdata%\...sparx...\dberror.txt` to find out if some DB SQL error is related.
- Turn off all MDGs to see if one of them might be the cause.
- Try a transfer to an empty schema and see if the copy has the same issue.
- Contact Sparx support if the error persists.

I guess that "install more memory" is not really what you want to hear ;-)

Comment: its a 32bit app so installing more memory will do nothing unless hes actually running out of memory (as opposed to the application running out of memory)

Comment: @Hue Unless he followed Gate's famous words that a computer never will need more than 600k or so (which is a urban legend, but funny though).

Answer (score 1):

I was constantly getting this error on startup. Running EA as Administrator seems to have resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me recently. I have 2 user accounts on the same PC and this first started to occur when I tried to open EA when both user logins were active on the machine. Even after restart and login to only one user had the same issue.

**Solution: Try Shift + Right click on the EA.exe file and run as a different user
Now provide your login and it should open.**